# Android linear layout for horizontal dependent view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout defined below which render two views - view1 and view2. For smaller screen sizes, the view2 is distorted.

Question - View2 needs to appear in the right side and view1 will accommodate whatever spaces remains at the left side. View2 is very constant in terms of dimension, drawable is well defined.

How can i achieve that? Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/view1"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:textSize="9pt"
              android:layout_weight = "0"
              android:maxWidth="260dp"
              android:minWidth="260dp"/>

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/view2"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="end"
              android:paddingStart="10dp"
              android:paddingEnd="10dp"
              android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried layout_width but couldn't achieve the result I am looking for. I'm newbie to android, any pointer would also be very helpful.

Comment: please attach screenshot to what u need to enable us to know which layout you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for view2 keep

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and set this for view1:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

this will make view 1 expand in the remaining width

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        tools:text="view1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        tools:text="view2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

use

> android:layout_weight=""

view1 use **70%** of screen (android:layout_weight="7")
view2 use **30%** of screen (android:layout_weight="3")